# Is there a mechanism in SQL that automatically generates a unique alphanumeric identifier for each row?

Tags: insert, uniqueidentifier

I need a unique identifier for objects in tables other than the autoincremented id and it would be helpful if it is generated by SQL after insert to take the load off of the web server

Comment: Which database platform are you using? Can you tag your question with the right one so you get a correct answer for it.

Answer (score -1):

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS table_name (
  prefix varchar(2) NOT NULL DEFAULT 'PRE',
  unique_id int(4) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  column_name varchar(100) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (unique_id),
  UNIQUE KEY (prefix, unique_id)
)
```

The above will give the following unique identifiers

```
PRE1
PRE2
PRE3
PRE4
PRE5
```

If you want it filled with leading zeros

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS table_name (
   prefix varchar(2) NOT NULL DEFAULT 'PRE',
   unique_id int(4) unsigned ZEROFILL NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
   column_name varchar(100) NOT NULL,
   PRIMARY KEY (unique_id),
   UNIQUE KEY (prefix, unique_id)
)
```

This will give

```
PRE0001
PRE0002
PRE0003
PRE0004
PRE0005
```